# Unable to move panel from right to bottom

Tags: visual-studio-code

I moved the Panel from bottom to the right of the workbench

[image: Panel on right]

After that, I cannot move the Panel back to the bottom. Dragging `Terminal` to the bottom has no effect. Closing and opening the Panel, restarting VS Code has no effect.

My `User Settings` shows the default setting of

```
"workbench.panel.defaultLocation": "bottom"
```

and after restarting Visual Studio Code, the Panel is still on the right. How can I move it back to the bottom?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an icon at the right end of the workbench to toggle the position.

[image]

It will reposition to the bottom.

[image]

As for the user settings it is the *default setting*. The position is different since you had previously changed it manually.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there should be an icon. It was hidden due to the narrow width. Once I expanded the Panel, I can see the toggle button again